# Conditional formatting in Excel or SQL Server

Tags: excel

I have about 500k records in an Excel sheet. I am tasked to identify sellers who have multiple purchase id and buyer id. For example, seller_id (12525) has three different purchase_id (8569, 8591, 8594) and buyer_id C160511, C160512, C160513).

What is the correct syntax to use in Excel 2013 that can easily identify the records I am interested? I searched the web about the conditional formatting.

```
location    Loc_Id  Purchase_id buyer_id    Seller_Id   Date
    CA      49456   8569        C160511     12525       5/3/2016
    CA      49456   8569        C160511     12525       5/3/2016
    CA      49456   8591        C160512     12525       5/3/2016
    CA      49456   8591        C160512     12525       5/3/2016
    CA      49456   8594        C160513     12525       5/3/2016
    CA      49456   8594        C160513     12525       5/3/2016
    TX      37140   8620        C170166     5621        1/24/2017
    TX      37140   8621        C170167     5621        1/24/2017
```

Comment: What's the expected result? Do you want a message box saying there are dupes and automatically filtering for the dupes? Do you just want to color dupes (and hope they are always close to one another to see the corresponding dupes)? Do you want different colors for different dupe groups? Do you want all dupes in the same color (across the entire table)? Maybe you can elaborate and possibly post a screenshot of the expected result? Also, what have you tried thus far? I am guessing it is a bit more complicated than just a `CountIf()` with anything `>1`?

Comment: i have tried in SQL server but through a several steps like load the records in a table, run couple scripts to identify them. i am interested in different colors. Thanks

Comment: @joe In your case both seller_id 12525 and 5621 have multiple Purchase_id and buyer_id, therefore both of them will have same color. Am I right in interpreting your question?

Comment: @India R, that is correct. Thanks. Joe

Comment: @joe Check the solution out and let me know if you still have any questions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you mention SQL Server, I'll answer using that. Honestly, your database is a MUCH better place to be doing this. With excel you would have two problems.

1. Identify these sellers
2. Apply conditional formatting based on 1.

And problem 1 is going to be heavy processing for 500k records in excel.

On to SQL Server:

```
SELECT Seller_ID, 
    CASE WHEN COUNT(DISTINCT Purchase_ID) > 1 THEN 'X' ELSE NULL END AS multiple_purchases,
    CASE WHEN COUNT(DISTINCT Buyer_ID) > 1 THEN 'X' ELSE NULL END AS multiple_buyers
FROM your_table_name
HAVING multiple_purchases = 'X' OR multiple_buyers='X'
GROUP BY Seller_ID;
```

So here we are just aggregating the records by `Seller_ID` and then using a `CASE` statement and aggregation formula `COUNT(DISTINCT <field>)` to get the number of distinct (unique) `purchase_id` and `buyer_id`. The `HAVING` clause tests to see if either of those tests produced a hit and, if not, it drops the record from the result set.

Comment: Thanks JNevill. i was able to do it in SQL Sever but i have to load 500k into a temp table then write something script to identify the problem. yours is much clear and sufficient. Thanks again

Comment: I just did a test run on it but encountered an error "incorrect syntax near the keyword 'GROUP'. I tried to include Purchase_ID and Buyer_ID in the GROUP by but still not resolved. not sure why

Comment: Perhaps put the GROUP BY above the HAVING clause. I can't recall if SQL Server is picky about the order (I'm assuming it is).

Answer (score 3):

Solution is bit lengthy but easy. I have included an extra condition as seller Id 5623 which does not have multiple buyer and purchase id. This is done to test this solution better. I have only highlighted sellerIds which has multiple Buyer and Purchase Id.

Image of my solution:- [image]

Note:- All the formulas or cell names are according to my solution as shown in the image

Now the solution. I will break it in different parts:-

Step 1:- Add a column say Purchase_Id_cnt and write this formula and drag it down till the end

```
=IF(SUMPRODUCT(($A$2:$A2=A2)*($C$2:$C2=C2))>1,0,1)
```

Step2 :- Add a column say Buyer_Id_cnt and write this formula and drag it down till the end

```
=IF(SUMPRODUCT(($B$2:$B2=B2)*($C$2:$C2=C2))>1,0,1)
```

Step3 :- Add Pivot table in the same sheet(you can use different sheet also. I used cell F1 in same sheet)

Step4:- Add another column say Header (You can give a better name) and enter this formula corresponding to Pivot table in cell I3 in my case and drag it down till the end

```
=IF(AND(G3>1,H3>1),1,0)
```

Step5:- Now Select/Higlight C2 to C11. Then go to conditional formatting. Select 'New Rule'. Then Select 'Use a formula to determine which cells to format'.

Step6:- Enter this formula under 'Format Values where this formula is True'

```
=IFERROR(VLOOKUP(C2,$F$3:$I$5,4,0),0)=1
```

Step7:-Don't press 'OK' yet. Click on 'Format'. Go in 'fill' tab. Choose any color you want. I choose yellow and then press 'OK'.

Done!!!

Comment: @ India.Rocket. Thanks for your quick response! i will have it tested later today. Thanks again. Joe

Answer (score 0):

Use the following formula in Conditional Formatting:

```
=COUNTIFS($B:$B,$B1,$C:$C,"<>" & $C1)>0
```

[image]